# postgresql trigger: disable auto commit and set isolation level

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, autocommit, transaction-isolation

i'm writing a trigger on database INSTEAD OF INSERT ON a table, that made some operation, then insert data into different related tables. Now i need to disable autocommit and set a different isolation level inside trigger, how can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable autocommit". Or at least, what do you think you mean by it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a setting that disables autocommit except for embedded SQL. If you try to set autocommit off in, say, PSQL, you'll see something like this error.

```
sandbox=# set autocommit=off;
ERROR:  SET AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF is no longer supported
```

Instead, use BEGIN to start a transaction. In PostgreSQL, you can start a transaction and set the isolation level in a single statement.  (Other platforms require multiple statements.) [Skeleton syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-begin.html) for PostgreSQL 9.2 is

```
BEGIN [ WORK | TRANSACTION ] [ transaction_mode [, ...] ]

where transaction_mode is one of:

    ISOLATION LEVEL { SERIALIZABLE   | REPEATABLE READ | 
                      READ COMMITTED | READ UNCOMMITTED }
    READ WRITE | READ ONLY
    [ NOT ] DEFERRABLE
```

End the transaction with either COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

you can then end with

```
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What's the benefit of this over the accepted answer from eight years ago?

Comment: I thought it will be helpful