# Transaction roll back not working in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, phppgadmin, php-pgsql

I am working on PostgreSQL 9.1.4 .

I am  inserting  the data into 2 tables its working nicely.

I wish to apply transaction for my tables both table exist in
 same DB. If my 2nd table going fail on any moment that time my 1 st
 table should be rollback.

I tried  the properties in "max_prepared_transactions" to a non zero 
 value in `/etc/postgres/postgres.conf`.   But Still Transaction roll
 back is not working.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Please *show the code you are running*, and any error messages.

Comment: Maybe you didn't turn off autocommit?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: your comment probably was valid at the time, but from my understanding, turning off autocommit now is neither needed nor possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17936997

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in postgresql you cannot write commit or roll back explicitly within a function.
I think you could have use a begin end block 
just write it simple

```
BEGIN;
   insert into tst_table values ('ABC');
   Begin
    insert into 2nd_table values ('ABC');
   EXCEPTION
    when your_exception then
    ROLL BACK;
   END;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you didn't started transaction.

Please, try

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO first_table VALUES(10);

  -- second insert should fail
  INSERT INTO second_table VALUES(10/0);

ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score -8):

I think it would be helpfull

```
  create proc DataInsertInTable
  as
  begin tran

  insert into Table1 values('Table1Data','XYZ')
  if(@@ERROR <>0)
  begin
        rollback tran;
        return 0
  end
  insert into Table2 values('Table2Data','ABC')
  if(@@ERROR <>0)
  begin
        rollback tran;
        return 0
  end
  commit Tran
  return 1
```

Comment: first, this is not postgresql code. second, even if it was, it is not related to question, not even close

Comment: This is a Microsoft SQL Server syntax